# Facebook Single Sign On - Stopped opening application with no explanation

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, single-sign-on

I integrated Facebook SSO in my Windows Phone 8 app yesterday and it was working properly. I tested it several times and on multiple devices and all was working. I submitted the code to my repository and today when I ran the code on the device the SSO wasn't working properly.

It starts off by starting the Facebook App as usual but then it shows me the dialog that it usually shows in the browser (with the typical message asking if I don't wish to install the Facebook application on my phone, which is installed) and even if I sign on it doesn't go back to my app.

I have not changed a single line of code since yesterday so I really have no idea of what must be happening. I checked if the Facebook App had been updated but it wasn't.

Does anyone have any idea of what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the Facebook app which they seem to have resolved by today. Now everything is working properly again.